# show $\mathcal{B}:=\{(a,b): a<b, a,b \in \Bbb{Q}\}$ forms a basis for $\Bbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

So I want to show that given the top space $\Bbb{R}$, that the collection

$$\mathcal{B}:=\{(a,b): a<b, a,b \in \Bbb{Q}\}$$

forms a basis using the following Lemma:

If $(X,\tau)$ is a top space and if for every $U \in \tau$ with $x \in U$, if one can find some $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that

$$x \in B \subset U.$$

Then $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis.

So my idea was to take some arbitrary open $U_x \in \tau$ as $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ for any given positive $\epsilon$. Then I can take

$$B:=(a,b); \text{where $a=x-\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, $b=x+\frac{\epsilon}{2}$}$$ then we have that

$$x \in B \subset U$$

as needed. Am I in the clear here?

Comment: No. $x\pm\varepsilon/2$ might not be rational

Comment: @FShrike I was afraid of that lol

Comment: @FShrike what if I used $\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: $x$ itself doesn't have to be rational. How about using the density of the rationals in the reals?

Comment: @MyMathYourMath Then, there is still the problem that $x$ might not be rational. $e\pm1/n$ is irrational for any integer $n$

Comment: ahh density of $\Bbb{Q}$ in $\Bbb{R}$!! @MordeusMorgenstern thx !

Comment: @MordeusMorgenstern so I go with: between $x$ and $x+\epsilon$ there is a rational and same for $x,x-\epsilon$??

Comment: Ye exactly, that works well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We prove that $\mathscr{B}$ is a basis for a topology on $\mathbb{R}$. This follows from the fact that the union of its elements is all of $\mathbb{R}$ and the intersection of two elements of $\mathscr{B}$ is either empty or another element of $\mathscr{B}$. Let $\mathscr{T}$ be the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$. The topology generated by $\mathscr{B}$ is coarser than $\mathscr{T}$. Here is a proof of this fact: take $U \in \mathscr{T}$ and rational $x \in U$. Then $U$ contains an open interval with center $x$ rational; this is because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ endowed with the standard topology, thus there exists $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x \in(x-q, x+q) \subset U$ (recall that the sum of rationals is rational). This proves that $\mathscr{T}$ is coarser than the topology generated by $\mathscr{B}$. Thus we can conclude that $\mathscr{B}$ generates the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Hope this helps!

Comment: So could I say that for $\epsilon>0$ $U$ in the standard topology is of the form $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ and between $x$ and $x+\epsilon$ there exists some $b \in Bbb{Q}$ and same goes for between $x-\epsilon,x$ then these rationals form the ball around $x$ that fits inside of $U$